# Vehicle audio system cuts off

Tags: electrical, audio, car, interference

So I've lately had a problem with my vehicle where my car's entire audio system will cut off for a brief period of time whenever I apply brakes (brake lights turn on), or when I use my turn signal lights or turn my headlights on. It seems as if parts of the electrical system such as the exterior lights and audio system are interfering with each other and I'm not sure what may be causing this.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: I'd start by checking the battery and alternator output.

Comment: When you say "cut off" - do you mean it appears the power is out (lights go off etc.) or does only the sound stop? Does it happen regardless of the audio input (i.e. does it happen only when playing the radio vs some other - CD? - source)?

Comment: sound stops, regardless of audio input, happens with the radio, and auxiliary connection so it doesn't appear to be exclusively an FM interference problem

Comment: it stops briefly for about two seconds and then resumes